# Chart.js Label Issue using chartjs-node-canvas

Tags: node.js, angular, charts, server

[Why I am getting boxes instead of labels, when chart is generated on server?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VBDq.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the text is broken is probably the encoding type method.(charset ut8
and I recommend attaching the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72975333/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solved it by adding a font file to ./assets/chartjsNodeCanvasFont/Lato-Black.ttf & registeringFont & chartCallback

```
    canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService.ChartJSNodeCanvas({
        width,
        height,
        plugins: {
            modern: ['chartjs-plugin-annotation', 'chartjs-adapter-moment'],
        },
        chartCallback: (ChartJS: any) => {
            ChartJS.defaults.font.family = 'Lato-Black';
            ChartJS.defaults.font.size = 16;
            ChartJS.defaults.font.weight = 'bold';
        }
    });
    canvasRenderService.registerFont('./assets/chartjsNodeCanvasFont/Lato-Black.ttf', { family: 'Lato-Black' });
```